# Install git to 32 bit Centos

Tags: centos, yum, git

Trying to install git to 32 bit Centos 7:

```
sudo yum install git
```

Got answer:

```
Requires: perl(Error)
```

How to fix that and install git? Why it is not trying to download perl if needed?

[image]

UPD:

Repositories list on my machine:

[image]

Comment: please as much as possible try not to put images but test in your question. it is very hard to work on images and search engine are bad at finding meaning in those. making your question almost invisible on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provide no information about which YUM repositories you are using (`yum repolist`), I can only guess that the package that provides perl(Error) does not exist in any of your configured repositories.

Looking at the CentOS 7 altarch repositories for i386, I was able to [find the package](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/i386/Packages/perl-Error-0.17020-2.el7.noarch.rpm) so you should try configuring [that repository](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/i386/Packages/centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.i686.rpm) and see if it works.

Comment: I have updated repo list in question body

Comment: You are missing base/7/i386 somehow, which would be the main repository with most of the packages, including the one you seem to need.

Comment: How I can see repositories content in order to find git?

Comment: The repository I have been linking is browsable, but the git package is here:  http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/i386/Packages/git-1.8.3.1-11.el7.i686.rpm

Comment: You have included the `extras` and `updates` parts of the CentOS repository, but somehow omitted the main part, named `os`. Perhaps running `yum-config-manager --enable os` would help? Description of the sub-directories of the CentOS package repository is in the CentOS FAQ: https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-92ba307b036080a16dbffa44486cde25c081fcca

Comment: I looked to `CentOS-Base.repo` file and found that section `[base]` has `enabled=0` record. Can I just change it to `enabled=1` ?

Comment: that should do it, curious why someone would do that though

Answer (score 0):

`perl(Error)` is provided by `perl-Error` package. It is available in the x86_64 repository, but it is noarch architecture package, so it should be compatible. Check if your repo provides it as well and eventually enable/take it from the x86_64 repo:

ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/perl-Error-0.17020-2.el7.noarch.rpm

The same for `perl(Term::ReadKey)` - package name `perl-TermReadKey`

Comment: How to check my repo provides `perl-Error`?

Comment: As mentioned in comments below GracefulRestart's answer, check your /etc/yum.repos.d and enable os repo (`enabled=1`). Then you should be able to get your packages. Eventually you may need to clean YUM cache (`yum clean all`).